# Variables in Ecto order by

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am just learning elixir and I can't figure out how to use variables inside the order by statement. I have two variables `sort` and `direction`. Here is the query I have working and would like to replace `desc` and `date` in the order by. I tried `[^direction: entry.^sort]` but it throws an error. Is there a way to use variables in the order by?

```
journal_entries = from entry in JournalEntry,
  preload: [
    :journal_entry_lines,
    journal_entry_lines: :journal_entry,
    journal_entry_lines: :chart_account
  ],
  where: entry.id in ^journal_entry_ids,
  order_by: [desc: entry.date],
  limit: 100,
  offset: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the key in your [keyword list](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#keyword-lists) is a variable, you are going to want to use the alternate syntax.

```
iex(1)> a = :desc
:desc
iex(2)> [{a, :b}]
[desc: :b]
```

You are also going to want to use the [`field/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#field/2) function to access the field name dynamically.

Something along the lines of the following should work

```
journal_entries = from entry in JournalEntry,
  preload: [
    :journal_entry_lines,
    journal_entry_lines: :journal_entry,
    journal_entry_lines: :chart_account
  ],
  where: entry.id in ^journal_entry_ids,
  order_by: [{^direction, field(entry, ^sort)}],
  limit: 100,
  offset: 0
```

This assumes that the `direction` variable is one of `:asc` or `:desc`, and your `sort` variable is a field on the schema.

Comment: How do I specify the field? Do I not pass it in as a string? I got this error `expected atom in field/2, got: "date"`

Comment: No, you are expected to pass in an atom. You can convert the string to an atom using [`String.to_atom/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_atom/1). But be careful with that as atoms are not garbage collected in Elixir. There is also an upper limit on how many atoms can exist within the system at any given time (this is configurable).

Comment: I found String.to_atom(), is that the best way to handle this?